# Was posting a question and clicked on tags tab to see what was available and lost all my question?

Tags: support

Was posting a question and clicked on tags tab to see what was available and lost all my question?

This format needs to be updated.  I am new to the site and don't find it very accessible.

Comment: Usually the site will save a draft post for you, but this functionality should not be relied on. Just like on any website on the Internet, if you leave the page you are working on, your work may be lost. However, the site is designed that when you do leave the page a warning appears stating, "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." You likely also chose to leave even after reading this warning. If you did not get this warning, I'd be curious what browser you are using.

Comment: Also note that you will see existing tags when you begin typing in the 'tags' field, which will help you find them. We will generally help out with tagging by editing them if needed as well - don't fret about it too much.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem in the past myself.  One thing to try is to press the "Ask Question" link again.  Sometimes the post was saved and you get it back.  (Similarly, press "Post Your Answer" for answers.)

If that doesn't work, it might be because you took longer than a [week to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/1438) (unlikely) or perhaps [pressed discard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126299/1438) by accident.  Otherwise, check to see if [your browser is supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).  If none of those are the issue, please update the question, add as many details as you can (what you did, error messages you saw, browser version, etc.), and retag as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).  That way we can get a developer to look at it.